# Updating user email does not update username when useEmailAsUsername is set

Tags: users, config

When the config setting [`useEmailAsUsername`](https://craftcms.com/docs/3.x/config/config-settings.html#useemailasusername) is set, I would expect updating a users' email address to also update the username field when saving the element. However, this does not occur unless you manually call `php craft utils/update-usernames`.

Should the username be updated when a users' email address is updated?

Is there a method to trigger this for the current user via a plugin or do I just need to update `username` alongside `email`?

Version: 3.5.15.1

Edit: This also prevents registration of a new user with the previous email address but does not indicate what the problem is clearly.

[image]

Comment: This feels like half-bug/half-feature request to me as I could see where people might want both behaviors. Can you make an issue for it? https://github.com/craftcms/cms/issues Going to go ahead and vote to close this here.

Comment: Thanks @BradBell, will do. As I was writing it I thought it might be more of a GitHub issue.